# How to reset QSlider?

Tags: pyqt5

My code has several QTreeWidget and QSlider widgets. I can delete all the items from the former with the method clear(). I was trying to do something similar but the class QSlider doesn’t have the clear method.
I tried

`myQSlider.setMinimum(0)`

`myQSlider.setMaximum(0)`

However, this didn’t see to have the desired effect. Is there any way to reset a QSlider widget in a straightforward way?

Comment: Why can't you just do `setValue(0)`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. By default, a QSlider has a range between 0-99 (included), and a value of 0. If you want to "reset" it to the default Qt properties, use `setRange(0, 99)` and `setValue(0)`; if you want it to reset to some custom "default" values of your program, store those values in some ways (even using the [Qt property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)) and reset them. Please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: For some reason (which I cannot figure out) even setting the range (with setRange or setMin/Maximum to zero) and values (with setValue(0)) does not erase the previously stored content. Having a limit of 100 elements is also a potential(future) problem so I might simply switch to a more sophisticated widget. P.S. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Fdez You're probably [re]setting values and/or connecting functions using for loops using the wrong reference. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Extracting an MRE from the code is not so simple as only the class using QSlider is close to 1,500 lines. I will try switching to QSpinBox or another QWidgetTree and check if that fixes the problem or at least points to its root cause. Thanks.